# Allowing user to edit WIX Burn variable

Tags: wix

I am using WIX 3.8 and have a Burn project that installs an MSI.

I have a string variable in the Burn project that has a default value that is passed to the MSI. I want to allow the user to edit this at install time but can't get it to work. How do you allow a user to edit a Burn string variable?

My current code is as below. The EditBox is shown but the default value is not displayed and the value entered is not passed to the MSI.

Bundle.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Name="My Bundle"
          Version="!(bind.packageVersion.Installer)" 
          Manufacturer="!(bind.packageManufacturer.Installer)"
          UpgradeCode="e71d08e2-0083-483d-acfb-4bf9adfd08b0">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLargeLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication ShowVersion="yes" LicenseUrl="" LogoFile="logo_64x64.jpg" ThemeFile="Theme.xml" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Variable Name="ADDRESS" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value="https://my.server.com" />

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="Installer" SourceFile="$(var.Installer.TargetPath)">
        <MsiProperty Name="ADDRESS" Value="[ADDRESS]" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>

  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Theme.xml:

```
...
<Page Name="Options">
    <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OptionsHeader)</Text>
    <Editbox Name="ADDRESS" X="11" Y ="120" Width="100" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" />  
    <Button Name="OptionsOkButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsOkButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="OptionsCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsCancelButton)</Button>
  </Page>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you've already found an answer to this question, if not, here's my stab at it.
It looks like your EditBox element is just missing the **ADDRESS** property reference. e.g.:

```
<Editbox Name="ADDRESS" X="11" Y ="120" Width="100" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" >[ADDRESS]</EditBox>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there more to this?  I followed this and I see my initial value and I'm able to edit it but when it gets passed to my MsiPackage the initial value is passed.

Comment: Is something missing still? Coz my varisable's default value only gets passed and not the updated one !